# Python: find_element_by_css_selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to click the login button with webdriver

```
<a class="login-btn" href="javascript:;" data-bind="click:loginSection.loginClick">
    <span class="btn-text">Login</span>
</a>
```

My code:

```
submit=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.login-btn').click()
```

or try this code:

```
submit=driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-btn').click()
```

Neither of these is working, need some advice. Thanks in advance

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.login-btn"}
```

Comment: Could you check whether your login form is inside a iframe?

Comment: What DebanjanB has suggested should work. Have you tried putting some delay just before that line? You may try like this `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Login').click()` as well. Btw, is that a slow loading page?

Comment: @Mouli nope, it's not :)

Comment: @SIM that's weird, it works with your suggestion :) Not a slow loading page, it just never clicked the button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To click on the *Login* button you can use either of the the following line of code :

- *LinkText* :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()
  ```
- *CssSelector* :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.login-btn > span.btn-text").click()
  ```
- Getting more granular with the *CssSelector* you can also use the following line of code :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.login-btn[data-bind='click:loginSection.loginClick'] > span.btn-text").click()
  ```

Update :
As you are seeing *NoSuchElementException* you can check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: It's not working. I am pretty sure the username and password are correct.

Comment: @Lara19 What does the error says? Can you paste the error with in the question?

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.login-btn[data-bind='click:loginSection.loginClick'] > span.btn-text"}