# Python: Webdriver is not working with css_selector

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I tried to use webdriver to login to two websites, A and B. But when I use the same way "find_element_by_css_selector", B was not working while A was working. I turned the javascript off, and find B's login section disappeared.

A's html:

```
<button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
  <span class="bigger-110">Login</span>
</button>
```

Code of A is working well:

```
submit=driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".width-35.pull-right.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary").click()
```

B's html:

```
<a class="login-btn" href="javascript:;" data-bind="click: loginSection.loginClick">
  <span class="btn-text">Login</span>
</a>
```

Code of B is not working:

```
submit=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.login-btn > span.btn-text").click()
```

Error says:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I posted another question before, [Python: find_element_by_css_selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578336/python-find-element-by-css-selector?noredirect=1#comment84153880_48578336), and someone suggested me to use "find_elements_by_link_text" and it works, but it only works with that one. I would still like to know how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Updated:

```
Link=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='login-btn'][@class='login-btn']"))).click()
```

Error:

```
TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Hi @Lara19, have you considered using XPath?

Comment: @Ali I can try! :)

Comment: See if my answer solves your issue, if it doesn't then I believe you will need to add delays right before the line that clicks on the `a` tag in html B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the time.sleep() delay approach and it actually worked on my end.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.easyauction.com.tw/index.html')

########
# Username and password go here
########

time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#IndexLogin > div > form > a.login-btn > span').click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide me the URL you accessing?

Comment: But I cannot provide you the username and password, is that okay?

Comment: No problem as long as I can view the same html content you're viewing.

Comment: It's in Chinese. The red button is the login button

Comment: I didn't see it login, and after that the google chrome in close. Oh wait! When I delete the driver.quit() it works!

Comment: Great! I was about to tell you to take the last line out :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164518/discussion-between-ali-and-lara19).

Comment: I sent you another message :)

Comment: Advice to use `time.sleep()` instead of ExplicitWait - it's a bad advice (-1)

Answer (score 3):

While you've already got an accepted answer, I want you to know the root cause of your issue

There are 2 links with the same class names: first one is hidden. You can check it with `len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("login-btn"))`.

That's why your code

```
Link=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='login-btn'][@class='login-btn']"))).click()
```

gives you `TimeOutException` - hidden element cannot be clickable

You can fix it by specifying index of button:

```
Link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class='login-btn'])[2]")))
Link.click()
```

or using search by link text:

```
Link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "確定登入")))
Link.click()
```

Note that search by link text will skip hidden link and handle only the visible one

Comment: Thank you! Yeah it works :D Just a question, does [2] represent its second root [@class='login-btn']?

Comment: In XPath indexation starts from `1`, but not from `0` as in Python

Comment: which means that you can find two class='login-btn' and what I need it the second one?

Comment: Yeap. `(//a[@class='login-btn'])[2]` means *get list of links with class name `"login-btn"` and return the second one*