# OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified error in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, invalidselectorexception

I am using chromedriver in CS to find an element using css selector however I receive the following error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

My code:

```
var body = driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(".add-to-cart.float-right.font-montserratSemiBold.text-11.lg:text-12.text-secondary.flex.flex-wrap.leading-articlesmall");
```

I am trying to find the element of the `Add to basket` buttons on [this website](https://www.pggoodeveryday.com/coupons/)

What is wrong with my selector and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

...implies that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance was unable to locate the desired [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) was invalid.

The [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) was almost perfect but the issue was with **`:`** as in `lg:text-12`. The character `:` have a special effect when used within a *css-selectors* as it is used in a couple of *css-selectors* variants. A few examples:

- `input:enabled`
- `p:first-child`
- `p:first-of-type`
- `:not(p)`
- `p:nth-child(2)`
- `p:nth-last-of-type(2)`

---

### Solution

There are two solutions.

- In the first approach you can escape the `:` character.
- In the second and the most effective approach instead of mentioning all the *class* attributes, you can use a single static *classname* which identifies all the elements with text as **Add to basket** as follows:

  - *css-selectors*:

    ```
    button.add-to-cart
    ```
  - *xpath*

    ```
    //button[contains(@class, 'add-to-cart')]
    ```

Snapshot:

[image: AddTobasket]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Python: find_element_by_css_selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578336/python-find-element-by-css-selector/48578370#48578370)

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector:

```
var body = driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(".add-to-cart");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding **double backslashes** escape character before : in lg:text-12 as shown below

```css
var body = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".add-to-cart.float-right.font-montserratSemiBold.text-11.lg\\:text-12.text-secondary.flex.flex-wrap.leading-articlesmall"));
```

Tested this in my local and worked fine returning eleven elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use findelements method in selenium 

List<WebElement> products=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add to basket')]"));

// if you want to pick 1 st product you can use below code 
        products.get(0).click();
```