# How to find_elements with multiple attributes using cssSelector Python and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to find all the elements that have `<a href=....>`  inside the `<div id="contents" ...>`

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="contents" class="style-scope">
    <div id="dismissible" class="style-scope">
        <a id="thumbnail" href="http://www.test.com">
```

Here is my python code:

```
items = driver.find_elements(By.cssSelector("div[id="contents"] a[id="thumbnail"]"))
```

It gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

Where do I need to put the comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

...implies that the [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) you have used contains a *SyntaxError*.

---

### Deep Dive

There are two approaches to write [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) as follows:

- Either you mention the value of the attributes within single quotes i.e. `'...'` and the entire locator within double quotes i.e. `"..."`. Example:

  ```
  "tag_name[attribute_name='attribute_value']"
  ```
- Or you mention the value of the attributes within double quotes i.e. `"..."` and the entire locator within single quotes i.e. `'...'`. Example:

  ```
  'tag_name[attribute_name="attribute_value"]'
  ```

---

### Solution

To identify all the elements having `<a href=....>` within `<div id="contents" ...>` you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id='contents'] a[href]")
```

However, incase of *css_selector*:

- *class* attributes can be shortened as *`.element_class`*
- *id* attributes can be shortened as *`#element_id`*

So precisely, your *locator strategy* can be:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#contents a[href]")
```

---

### Getting Granular

To be more canonical, you may like to consider the *`id`* attribute of the `<a>` element as well i.e. *`thumbnail`*. So effectively the [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447) would be:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#contents a#thumbnail[href]")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax related error. you are trying to come up with a list of the webelements which contain the different HTML's?

```
items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a#thumbnail")
```

Comment: but on the page, there are other <a id="thumbnail" that I don't want... so that why I wanted to also PARSE with the div id="contents"... to check for both... how would I do that ?