# Selenium CssSelector written in python raising timeout error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, timeout

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(2)>input')))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(2)>input').send_keys(element[0])
```

The portion HTML script with CSS searched of the website
[image: the portion HTML script with CSS searched of the website]

Both codes are not working. Format looks correct.

Maybe CSS Selector seems to be the problem?

The ID attribute changes every time when there is a different input prior to this page

Code raising a **TimeoutExceptionError**

Comment: there's an ID attribute there... I'd use that to locate as it should be unique.  Ex: xpath of: //input[@id='t_306']

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically the [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

```
td:nth-child(2)>input
```

is correct but still have a logical error.

Though the above [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271653/7429447) indicates immediate `<input>` descendant of second `<td>` child, but of whom? In this case you have to provide a reference node uniquely identified by [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) first.

As an example:

- With respect to `<table>` tag:

  ```
  table td:nth-child(2) > input
  ```
- With respect to `<tbody class="z-row">` tag:

  ```
  tbody.z-row td:nth-child(2) > input
  ```