# Selenium Web Scraping (InvalidSelectorException)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, invalidselectorexception

I am trying to web scrap a website with navigating the different pages.

I tried this code on another website that works for scrapping. I have now trying to scrap another website and failed.

It shows that *"selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified"*

But I can't find the issue.. can anyone help to solve this.. Many thanks!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
)

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.28hse.com/buy/residential/a1")

for i in range(3):
    all_cells = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item property_item")
    
    for cell in all_cells:
        names = cell.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".areaUnitPrice.separation").text

        if len(names) > 0:
            print(names[0].text)
        else:
            print("--- no name ---")

    next_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pagination_hi[2]")
    next_btn.click()
    try:
        print(f"Done page {i+1}")
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".product-brief-wrapper"))
        )
    except:
        print("Wait failed")
```

Comment: What code line gives you the exception?

Answer (score 0):

This [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

```
.pagination_hi[2]
```

definitely looks error prone. Possibly you intend to use:

```
.pagination
```

---

Additionally, you also need to change:

```
.item property_item
```

to

```
.item.property_item
```

Answer (score 0):

As @undetected Selenium mentioned lots of error in your code.

1.

```
all_cells = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item property_item")
```

It should be when you are using css selector each class name should use `.`

```
 all_cells = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item.property_item")
```

2. names = cell.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".areaUnitPrice.separation").text

`find_elements()` returns list of elements and its not having property `text`

So this should be

```
names = cell.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".areaUnitPrice.separation")
```

3. pagination link

   `next_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pagination_hi[2]")`

if you have two same elements present on the page and wants to select the second one using css selector you should use.

```
.pagination_hi:nth-of-type(2)
```

Ideally your code should like

```
next_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pagination_hi:nth-of-type(2)")
```

or you can use element uniquely identified on the page.

```
 next_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pagination_hi >a[rel='next']")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What does that mean:

(1) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Shall be related to the next_btn?

(2) How am i suppose the scrap the text in .areaUnitPrice.separation?

Much thanks!!!!!!!!!!