# Unable to locate element (button) in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Selenium does not find the button "Consultar". I already tried copying and finding by xpath, id, partial_text, and text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

url = 'https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/sistema-reune.htm'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r"/Users/Test/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
```

Information about the button :

```
<img src="../img/bt_consultar.gif" name="Consultar" onclick="VerificaSubmit()" style="cursor: pointer; cursor:pointer;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Consultar** button element  is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/sistema-reune.htm')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#LGPD_ANBIMA_global_sites__text__btn"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/reune/default.asp']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[name='Consultar'][src*='bt_consultar']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/sistema-reune.htm')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='LGPD_ANBIMA_global_sites__text__btn']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/reune/default.asp']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@name='Consultar' and contains(@src, 'bt_consultar')]"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but the methods above continue to present the same error of `no such element: Unable to locate element`

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I just ran using xpath and css_selector and i got some errors with this line of code : `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#LGPD_ANBIMA_global_sites__text__btn"))).click()`

After I erased it, the webdriver found the button.