# Selenium | Unable to locate input element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, shadow-root

No idea how to address this input text field element with selenium / Java (openjdk 11 2018-09-25).

I tried xpath, cssSelector etc. it never works. Its always "Unable to locate element".

```
<slot name="input">
   <input part="value" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="vaadin-text-field-input-3">
</slot>
```

This did NOT work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-labelledby='vaadin-text-field-input-3']")).sendKeys("test");
```

Is there a solution for this?

UPDATE:

This thread solved partly my problem. The solution that worked for me can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486285/selenium-shadow-root-element-input-is-not-reachable-by-keyboard) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486285/selenium-shadow-root-element-input-is-not-reachable-by-keyboard).

Comment: please share a link to that page or the HTML of the entire page, not the single element

Comment: It might be that the number `3` is not static, i.e., it maybe changing everytime, in which case, you may use something like this: `//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,'vaadin-text-field-input')]`, which again depends on how many elements are there with `aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input'` attribute. If only one, then fine, otherwise you may have to use another stragegy. Could you post more html code for analysis?

Comment: <div class="vaadin-text-field-container">
 <label part="label" id="vaadin-text-field-label-3"></label>
   <div part="input-field" id="vaadin-text-field-input-3">
     <slot name="prefix"></slot>
      <slot name="input">
        <input part="value" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="vaadin-text-field-input-3">
      </slot>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Is that `3` constant ? or is it changing often ?

Comment: From what I see and know it is constant.

Comment: Not yet. There is this: `#shadow-root (open)  <div class="vaadin-text-field-container">` No idea how to find a solution to this.

Comment: Yes. It is along time ago so I do not remember what answer helped. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
          By.cssSelector("div.vaadin-text-field-container div[part=input-field][id^='vaadin-text-field-input'] slot[name='input'] > input[part='value'][aria-labelledby^='vaadin-text-field-input']")
    )).sendKeys("pixelhead");
```

- [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
      By.xpath("//div[@class='vaadin-text-field-container']//div[@part='input-field' and starts-with(@id, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]//slot[@name='input']/input[@part='value' and starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]")
   )).sendKeys("pixelhead");
```

Comment: No results so far. This message shows the terminal: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: slot[name='input'] > input[part='value'][aria-labelledby^='vaadin-text-field-input-3'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: How about the xpath?

Comment: @pixelhead Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: It does not work. There is this: `#shadow-root (open)  <div class="vaadin-text-field-container">` thing. It probably has an effect.

Comment: [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56380091/7429447) is a different story all together. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670415/7429447) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447) discussion.

Comment: Now it works. With this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486285/selenium-shadow-root-element-input-is-not-reachable-by-keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

**Xpath:**

```
//div[@class='vaadin-text-field-container']//descendant::input[@part='value' and starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If this is unique `//div[@class='vaadin-text-field-container']//descendant::input[@part='value' and starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]` then you need to check for the below conditions as well.

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.

   **Solution:** switch to iframe/frame/frameset first and then interact with this web element.
2. Check if it's in any `shadow-root`.

   **Solution:** Use `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector` to have returned a web element and then operates accordingly.
3. Make sure that the element is rendered properly before interacting with it. Put some `hardcoded delay` or `Explicit wait` and try again.

   **Solution:** `time.sleep(5)` or

   `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='vaadin-text-field-container']//descendant::input[@part='value' and starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]"))).send_keys("test")`
4. If you have redirected to a `new tab/ or new windows` and you have not **switched** to that particular `new tab/new window`, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.

   **Solution:** switch to the relevant window/tab first.
5. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first `switch to default content` and then interact with it.

   **Solution:** switch to default content and then switch to respective iframe.

You can start debugging from step1.

**Update:**

Solution specific to the problem:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement inputButton = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector('#TextFieldTitle').shadowRoot.querySelector('#vaadin-text-field-input-3 > slot:nth-child(2) > input')");
inputButton.sendKeys("test");
```

in the place of `paste query selector here` you will have to go to dev tools again in goog chrome by pressing F12, and then

1. Go to that input box
2. Do a right click
3. Select copy
4. Select copy JS path.
5. Ctrl + v into notepad to see what you've got from the dev tool.

It'd be something like this:

```
document.querySelector("#vaadin-text-field-input-3 > slot:nth-child(2) > input")
```

replace this `paste query selector here` with the stuff that is wrapped inside  `""`

Comment: There is this:
`#shadow-root (open) 
<div class="vaadin-text-field-container">`
Does that shadow root has an effect? I have not seen any ifarmes.

Comment: working on Java solution

Comment: @pixelhead: Please check out the Update section above.

Comment: There is a message in the terminal again:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: Document.querySelector: 'document.querySelector("#vaadin-text-field-input-3 > slot:nth-child(2) > input")' is not a valid selector

Comment: This is the exact JS path:
`document.querySelector("#TextFieldTitle").shadowRoot.querySelector("#vaadin-text-field-input-3 > slot:nth-child(2) > input")`

Comment: Updated again in the same update section, Please verify.

Comment: Thats strange. I see the cursor blinking in the input field but also get in the terminal this message:
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <input> is not reachable by keyboard`

Comment: Now it works. With this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486285/selenium-shadow-root-element-input-is-not-reachable-by-keyboard).

Comment: That issue that you've asked here is about no such element exception which we could resolve it here, the other ticket has a different exception. As per SO guidline we solve one issue per ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Per the html provided, this works:

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@part='value' and contains(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]"]`

```
x = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@part='value' and contains(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]")))
x.send_keys('This is typed here by selenium')
print(f"the typed text in input box is: {x.get_attribute('value')}")
```

Output:

```
the typed text in input box is: This is typed here by selenium

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: contains can also have more than one matching HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like part of HTML looks like:

```
<div class="vaadin-text-field-container">
    <label part="label" id="vaadin-text-field-label-3"></label>
    <div part="input-field" id="vaadin-text-field-input-3">
        <slot name="prefix"></slot>
        <slot name="input">
            <input part="value" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="vaadin-text-field-input-3">
        </slot>
    </div>
</div>
```

Much better is to build your XPATH locator from some id field:

> //div[@id='vaadin-text-field-input-3']//input[contains(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]"]

Also, as mentioned earlier have to check:

- if it is unique for this page
- if the `input` element is not dynamic

If you found solved that comment you could move to the code part and use the founded locator with WebDriver:

```
driver.findElement(
     By.xpath("//div[@id='vaadin-text-field-input-3']//input[contains(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input-3')]"]"
)).sendKeys("test");
```

Also, keep in mind that you have to know that element is already loaded on a page. As suggested before you could use some [explicit wait](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver) for your element.