# Find previous element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I have HTML:

```
<div class="value">
    <div style="float: right;">100.00</div>
    <span class="yellow">Frequency:</span>
</div>
```

With selenium By.XPATH '//*[text()="Frequency:"]' I'm able to locate the `<span>` element. My goal is to get the innerText of the previous `<div>`.

Can I do it with selenium or should I use bs4 for this task?

I tried selenium.parent with documentation, but unable to do.

PS: I can't find the parent element or the div I need directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the text from the `<div>` tag i.e. ***100.00*** wrt the `<span>` you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Frequency:']//preceding::div[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Frequency:']//preceding::div[1]").text)
  ```

Comment: That`s mega. I bookmarked locator strategies, big thanks.
::1 it is ::before in css, am i right?

Comment: Nopes, using [_css_selector_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) you can't traverse upwards.