# VBA Selenium Scraping text from label

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, label

How do I extract the following "label" using the chrome driver in Selenium for VBA? The information that I want is "Character 3"

HTML:

```
<label for="frmentermemorableinformation1:strEnterMemorableInformation_memInfo1">Character 3 &nbsp;</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the text **Character 3** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

  ```
  Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("label[for^='frmentermemorableinformation1'][for$='strEnterMemorableInformation_memInfo1']").Text
  ```
- Using [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

  ```
  Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath("//label[starts-with(@for, 'frmentermemorableinformation1') and contains(@for, 'strEnterMemorableInformation_memInfo1')]").Text
  ```