# How to obtain the number of elements with classname "xyz" through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element, locate

Is it possible to do something like this? I want to know the number of elements with the class property set to 'gsc-cursor-page'.

```
pages_nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gsc-cursor')
pages = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gsc-cursor-page')
for pages in pages_nav:
    print("len(pages)")
```

As shown below are (.gsc-cursor-page) inside (.gsc-cursor)
So how can I obtain the number of elements with classname 'gsc-cursor-page'.

[image: Html code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the number of elements with *`classname`* property set to ***gsc-cursor-page*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "gsc-cursor-page")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='gsc-cursor-page']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='gsc-cursor-page']")))
  ```

---

### Update

The output of `15`, `13` and `13` is perfect as the [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) and the [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) looks for the elements ***only*** with *classname* *`gsc-cursor-page`* i.e. ***perfect match*** and there can be some more elements outside the scope of the snapshot you provided and some more elements which also contains the *classname* *`gsc-cursor-page`*.

---

### Solution

Your effective line of code will be:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.gsc-cursor div.gsc-cursor-page")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gsc-cursor']//div[@class='gsc-cursor-page']")))
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but they do not return the expected value. They return 15, 13 and 13. I have updated the picture of the html tags. There are a total of 10 elements with the classname 'gsc-cursor-page' wihin the 'gsc-cursor' class.

Comment: Yeah you are right, there are other elements named under same syntax. But I just had to move futher out in the scope of the CSS_SELECTOR path. By running  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.gsc-resultsRoot.gsc-tabData.gsc-tabdActive div.gsc-cursor-box.gs-bidi-start-align div.gsc-cursor div.gsc-cursor-page"))) I will get the expected result. Thanks for showing the way :) GG.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do

```
pages = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.gsc-cursor-page')
```

find_elements instead of find_element, which returns a list. And then you can count the number of elements in the list with

```
len(pages)
```

Comment: Nope, it returns a result of 142 when it should be 10

Comment: Then you probably need to update css selector or xpath selector for something more precise, however this answer gets you the number of elements with classname "xyz"