# .Net 6 Console application fails with OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException when runs with Windows task scheduler

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

That's it basically, when i run the app manually it runs fine, but when I run it with task scheduler it fails in the middle of application with the exception:

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name ="start_year"]"}

The strange part is, the program mostly works with the scheduler, it calls a few webapi before it fails, loads appsettings.json values, but when it is scheduled on windows (I tried with a few windows server and reproducable with windows 10 home as well), when Selenium loaded a site and logged in, than fails to find a dom element every time.

I tried to run with highest privileges, tried setting the run wether user not logged in in scheduler, I set the value of my app folder in task scheduler Start in textbox, it seems like no changes in task scheduler settings helps.

I using IHostBuilder and dependency injection with latest 4.8.0 Selenium.Support and Selenium.WebDriver nuget packages.

I using implicitwait and the following chromeoptions:

```
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
        {
            BinaryLocation = config["chromebinarypath"],
        };



            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");// disabling extensions
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");// applicable to windows os only
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");// overcome limited resource problems
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");// Bypass OS security model
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");// Bypass OS security model
        

        _chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        _chromeDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);
        //Important, enables waiting for dom objects till they available for 10 seconds.
        _chromeDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

Can someone point me to right direction?

Maybe it is some kind of Selenium bug?
Maybe the issue is related to the used IHost, and I should just call the classes without dependecy injection?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name ="start_year"]"}
```

...implies that the desired element wasn't ***visible*** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) while `FindElement()` was invoked.

---

### Solution

Possibly you need to tweak the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) a bit by removing the `*` from the [*css selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) as follows:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[name ="start_year"]"));
```

As an alternative, you can also use `By.Name` as follows:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("start_year"));
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not answer the question.
Stange enough Im not even use CssSelector, I use FindElement(By.Name(elementName), where the elementName is start_year in this case.
Further testing revealed, It looks like click events not working when the program is scheduled by task scheduler.
Somehow if I check the run when the user logged in checkbox in task scheduler, it works, but if I check the checkbox run wether the user logged in or not, than fails with this strange message, and cant log in.
I think somehow the page cant receive focus when running in the background.