# python selenium 4.8.0 -

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

So i have a log-in script and i just try find element by class on newest version of selenium (4.8.0)

code:

```py
button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'just class name')
```

AND this code not working.

my stuff:

- firefox driver - 0.32.1 (2023-02-02, b7f075124503)
- selenium 4.8.0

this is how the documentation searches for elements - `By.CLASS_NAME`, `By.ID`, etc...

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/

tried other variations of the code like `find_element_by_ID` and etc, installed an additional library for the selenium (I do not remember the name).

Comment: Please provide at least the relevant html or url to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`By.CLASS_NAME`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536022/7429447) accepts only single classname as an argument. So you can't pass multiple classnames.

---

### Solution

You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using the classname *just*:

  ```
  button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'just')
  ```
- Using the classname *class*:

  ```
  button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'class')
  ```
- Using the classname *name*:

  ```
  button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'name')
  ```

As an alternative, you can also use a [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) as follows:

```
button = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".just.class.name")
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS classes and IDs never contain spaces. You can check if this class exists in the DOM by typing in browser console:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class_name')
```

change `class_name` with class name you looking for. If the element has multiple classes each is prefixed by a period (.).

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class_name1.class_name2')
```

Comment: The shortcut to `document.querySelectorAll()` in the browser console is `$$()`, e.g. `$$('.class_name')`. It will save you some typing. `$x()` will do the same thing but for XPath.

Comment: Also, `.querySelectorAll()` takes CSS selectors so a space means descendant, not class. Each class must be prefixed with a period (.).