# How to locate either of two similar <p> elements inside a <div>

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception, selenium-java

I cannot locate `err_message` elements for email and password. I'm getting an error as:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > form:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(3)"}
```

Tried with:

```
.form-signin .form_item .err_message:nth-child(1), .err_message:nth-of-type(1)
```

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Comment: you should start from form.sign-in , not body , there can be anything popping up in the structure you are not aware of

Comment: I tried .form-signin p:nth-child(2), and it thows exception too , org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".form-signin p:nth-child(2)"}

Comment: Please don't post [code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Place it directly into your question and format it as a code sample (fifth button from the left).

Comment: ok I will next time, thank you

Answer (score 0):

A CSS selector which starts from the body element and uses `>` to identify every descendant down to the target, as you have done, is **not** a great idea, because as soon as you move things around in your document, the selector will break. Instead, use classes or ids to target elements directly.

In your case, the only ids you have in your code are on the input fields, but as these immediately precede your error message elements, you could use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to target your error message elements:

The error message for the email field could be selected with any of the following:

- `#email + p`
- `#email + .err_message`
- `#email + p.err_message`

The error message for the password field could be selected with any of the following:

- `#password + p`
- `#password + .err_message`
- `#password + p.err_message`

Answer (score 0):

To locate the `<p>` elements you can use the *Email Address* and *Password* field as a reference identified through unique attributes and you can use the following [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

- `<p>` tag for *Email Address* field:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.login_page form.form-signin div.form_item input#email +p"));
  ```
- `<p>` tag for *Password* field:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.login_page form.form-signin div.form_item input#password +p"));
  ```