# How to identify a certain text inside each element in an iteration of elements using Selenium and C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I've been learning automation with C# for some weeks now, though I'm progressing in a slow manner.  I'm currently trying to do a certain test using a mock page (automationexercise.com).

The page mocks an E-commerce.

I want to capture the products listed in the main page so I can store their properties and test them.

The original html from the page looks like this:
There is a div, which contains 34 divs with the class `class="col-sm-4"` and inside each one of those we have a content like this:

[image]

I want to capture the content of the paragraph that appears in the picture that is present in each one of those 34 divs containing the product name.

I wrote this code expecting it to print the name of each product but it returns a selector error:

```
IList<IWebElement> productos = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class=col-sm-4]"));

foreach (IWebElement element in productos)
{

    IWebElement asd = element.FindElement(By.XPath("./div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]"));

    TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(asd.Text);
}
```

I have also tried some more variations, none had any success at all except the following Xpath which returns the content of the paragraph in the firs product 34 times.

```
//div[@class='productinfo text-center']//p
```

Can someone please help me understand the correct way to build the selector (be it xpath or css selector) in this case?

Comment: Maybe this page is loaded dynamically with AJAX. In that case all of your attempts will fail, because the DOM is not fully created at the time of querying.

Comment: Souldn't in that case also fail the iteration trough the product items? i forgot to specify it, but i'm able to capture the class="col-sm-4" objects @zx485

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little tweak in the [*CssSelector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) as:

```
div.productinfo p
```

all the items can be identified as follows:

[image: 40]

---

### Solution

To capture the products listed in the main [webpage](https://automationexercise.com/) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.Url = "https://www.allbanglanewspaper.xyz/";
  IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.productinfo p"));
  foreach (IWebElement ele in elements)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);
  }
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  driver.Url = "https://www.allbanglanewspaper.xyz/";
  IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'productinfo')]//p"));
  foreach (IWebElement ele in elements)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Blue Top
  Men Tshirt
  Sleeveless Dress
  Stylish Dress
  Winter Top
  ...
  ...
  ...
  Stylish Dress
  Winter Top
  Summer White Top
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! it really worked like magic! i hadn't seen that kind of cssselector before!Also helped me a lot understanding the nonesense that was trying to capture the card first and then trying to acces the paragraph!

Answer (score 0):

To capture the product names, you can use either XPath or CSS selector as following.

Xpath -> `IList<IWebElement> products = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='col-sm-4']//p"));`

CSS -> `IList<IWebElement> products = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.col-sm-4 p"));`

```
foreach (IWebElement product in products)
{
    TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(product.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the browser console and JavaScript the code

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.col-sm-4').forEach(div => console.log(div.querySelector('div.productinfo p').textContent))
```

gives a similar error while

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.col-sm-4').forEach(div => console.log(div.querySelector('div.productinfo p')?.textContent))
```

outputs all product names and some undefined.

So I would try

```
IList<IWebElement> productos = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class=col-sm-4]"));

foreach (IWebElement element in productos)
{
    try
    {
        IWebElement asd = element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.productinfo p"));

        TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(asd.Text);
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) { }

}
```

That can then probably be simplified to

```
IList<IWebElement> productos = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class=col-sm-4] div.productinfo p"));

foreach (IWebElement element in productos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of those p's with:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('.col-sm-4')].map(div => div.querySelector('.productinfo p')?.innerText)
""")
```