# How to select element which is located around the end of the page?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to select element form a website. the element which I am trying to find the text only which is located inside the div. I am able to select the first 51 text but not able to select the text after 51 elements. Tried also scrolling effect but not working.

I am using Visual Studio, Selenium and C# to do this. And my working code which is able to select only the first 51 rows are below:

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Url = "https://www.allbanglanewspaper.xyz/";
        var elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("allbanglanewspaperslogo"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
        {
            IWebElement element = elements[i];
            String name = 
            element.FindElement(By.ClassName("banglanewspaperlistname")).Text;
            Console.WriteLine(name);  
        }
```

Anybody has any suggestion to get the info for other element?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *ClassName* as *allbanglanewspaperslogo* you can traverse one step deeper to the decendant `<div>` tag containing the class *`banglanewspaperlistname`*

---

### Solution

To capture the ***banglanewspaperlistname*** in the [webpage](https://www.allbanglanewspaper.xyz/) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.Url = "https://www.allbanglanewspaper.xyz/";
  IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.allbanglanewspaperslogo div.banglanewspaperlistname"));
  foreach (IWebElement ele in elements)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);
  }
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  driver.Url = "https://www.allbanglanewspaper.xyz/";
  IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='banglanewspaperlistname' and text()]"));
  foreach (IWebElement ele in elements)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Daily Prothom alo', 'Bangladesh Pratidin', 'Ittefaq', 'Daily kaler kantho', 'Daily Naya Diganta', 'Daily Amar Sangbad', 'Protidiner Sangbad', 'Jugantor', 'Daily Sangram', 'Daily Manab Zamin', 'Dainik Amadershomoy', 'Bonik Barta', 'Samakal', 'Janakantha', 'Jai Jai Din', 'Daily Bhorer Kagoj', 'Arthoniteer Kagoj', 'Daily Inqilab', 'Sangbad', 'Manob Kantha', 'Daily Suprobhat', 'Bangladesh Journal', 'Daily Dinkal', 'Alokito Bangladesh', 'Ajker Bazar', 'Amadar Orthoneeti', 'Bangladesh Post', 'Sorejomin Barta', 'Khabar Patra', 'Vorer Pata', 'Shomoyer Alo', 'Kal Bela', 'Natun Barta', 'Share biz', 'Daily Bartoman', 'Ajkaler Khobor', 'Sangbad Konika', 'Khola Kagoj', 'Gonokantho', 'Daily Star', 'Daily Observer', 'Financial Express', 'Desh Rupantor', 'Bangladesher Khabor', 'Bd Bulletin', 'Daily Jagran', 'Business Standard', 'Dhaka Tribune', 'Business Post', 'Ajker Patrika', 'Dainik Bangla', 'E Prothom Alo', 'E BD Pratidin', 'E Jugantor', 'E Samakal', 'E Janakantha', 'E Bonik Barta', 'E Naya Diganta', 'E Financial Express', 'E Ittefaq', 'E Kalerkantho', 'E amadershomoy', 'E Jai Jai Din', 'E Daily Inqilab', 'Daily Star Epaper', 'E Business Standard', 'E Share biz', 'E Bhorer Kagoj', 'E Bangladesh Today', 'BD News 24', 'Bangla News 24', 'Jago News 24', 'Priyo', 'Amadershomoy', 'Bd24live', 'Risingbd', 'Daily Bangladesh', 'Gonews 24', 'Dhaka Post', 'Bangla Tribune', 'Bangla Insider', 'UNB', 'BSS News', 'Barta24', 'Amar Desh', 'Sarabangla', 'Breaking News', 'Dhaka Times', 'DMP News', 'Natun Barta', 'The Report 24', 'Somoyer Konthosor', 'Bangla Telegraph', 'Bdview24', 'Bd Journal365', 'Artho Suchak', 'Share News 24', 'Sunbd24', 'Orthosongbad', 'Poriborton', 'Nagorik Kantha', 'Media Khabor', 'Sotta Sangbad', 'Dhaka Post', '1News BD', 'Aparadh Chokh', 'Times World', 'Desh News', 'RTNN', 'Desher Sangbad', 'Last News Bd', 'Bangla Daily 24', 'Protikhon', 'Prime News', 'MTNews', 'Deshe Bideshe', 'Boichitra News', 'Barta Bangla', 'Sangbad Protidin', 'BD Type', 'Zoom Bangla', 'Sheersha Sangbad', 'SNN24', 'Alert News', 'Crime Reporter', 'Khobor Protidin', 'BD Cricteam', 'Shersha News', 'Bbc 24 News', 'Tulpar24', 'Bangla Kagoj24', 'Latest bd news', 'Barta Bazar', 'Dhaka Protidin', 'Eibela', 'Sada Kalo', 'PBD', 'Techshohor', 'Tech Zoom', 'Channel I', 'Independent Tv', 'Somoy News', 'NTV BD', 'Channel 24 BD', 'RTV', 'Ekushey TV', 'ATN Bangla', 'Jamuna TV', 'SATV', 'Desh TV', 'Maasranga TV', 'Bangla Vision', 'Ekattor TV', 'ATN News', 'Channel9 BD', 'My TV', 'Boishakhi TV', 'Mohona TV', 'Gazi TV (GTV)', 'BTV', 'Channel 16', 'Gaan Bangla', 'Asian TV', 'Daily Azadi', 'Daily Purbokone', 'Amader Comilla', 'Daily Purbanchal', 'Ctg Times', 'Coxsbazar News', 'Ukhiya News', 'Khulna News', 'Matha Bhanga', 'Rajshahi News 24', 'Chattagram News', 'Daily Khowai', 'Daily Karatoa', 'Satkhira News', 'Dainik Sylhet', 'Daily Coxsbazar', 'Uttorpurbo', 'Ajker Jamalpur', 'Amader Barisal', 'Surma Times', 'Daily Sylhet', 'Dinajpur News', 'Kuakata News', 'Chadpur Times', 'Mukto Khobor 24', 'Teknaf News', 'Bogra Sangbad', 'Rajshahir Somoy', 'Chandpurweb', 'Barisal News', 'Sylhet Express', 'Laksmipur 24', 'Prothom Feni', 'Amar Noakhali', 'Chakaria News', 'Gramer Kagoj', 'Andoloner Bazar', 'Khulnanchal', 'Mymensingh Pratidin', 'AFP', 'The Guardian', 'Abc News', 'Dailystar', 'Moscow Times', 'Independent', 'New Age', 'Yahoo News', 'Daily Sun', 'Bangladesh Today', 'News Today', 'Financial Express', 'Nytimes', 'Hindustan Times', 'CNN', 'Aljazeera', 'BBC', 'NDTV', 'Reuters', 'Foxnews', 'GEO', 'Sky News', 'Euronews', 'Press Tv', 'Discovery', 'CCTV', 'Ananda Bazar', 'Aaj Kaal', 'Kolkata24x7', '24 Ghanta', 'ABP Ananda', 'NDTV Bengali', 'Syandan Patrika', 'Sangbad Pratidin', 'Bartaman Patrika', 'Ganashakti', 'Asomiya Pratidin', 'Nababarta Prasanga', 'Eisamay', 'Uttarbanga Sambad', 'Ebela', 'Dainik Sambad', 'Aamader Malda', 'Ganashakti', 'Education Bangla', 'Educationboard Result', 'National University']
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detaild discussions in:

- [How to identify a certain text inside each element in an iteration of elements using Selenium and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76443437/7429447)